# Using uniform coloring in MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting, matrix, color

I have a rectangular matrix, which is `m`-by-10.  Each element is either 0 or 1.  I would like 0 to correspond to white elements, and 1 to red elements.  This works fine if `m = 100` or similar small values:

```
m = 100;
list = Table[Table[RandomInteger[], {j, 1, 10}], {i, 1, m}];
Tally[Flatten[list]]
MatrixPlot[list, FrameTicks -> None, ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Red}]
```

[image: MP1]

However, if I choose `m = 200`, the coloring becomes strange and no longer only white or red:

```
m = 200;
list = Table[Table[RandomInteger[], {j, 1, 10}], {i, 1, m}];
Tally[Flatten[list]]
MatrixPlot[list, FrameTicks -> None, ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Red}]
```

[image: MP2]

Why do I see orange if each element is either 0 or 1?  Is there any way I can correct this so that the only colors that appear are white or red?

Setting `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` does not seem to correct the problem:

[image: MP3]

Comment: Did you try with `ArrayPlot`?

Comment: Try `MatrixPlot[data, Frame -> False, MaxPlotPoints -> Infinity]` and `MatrixPlot[data, Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
 MaxPlotPoints -> Infinity]`. I think, what you are seeing is the effect of downsampling combined with interpolation.

Comment: `ArrayPlot` seems to work as expected. (Also note that for `Hue`, `Hue[0] === Hue[1] === Red`, so the appropriate output would be all `Red`.)

Comment: Here's a way to confirm what kglr suggests works: `MatrixPlot[RandomInteger[1, {10, 300}], Frame -> False,
      MaxPlotPoints -> Infinity
      ] // Rasterize // ImageData // Flatten[#, 1] & // 
  DeleteDuplicates // Length`. That should be two, showing that allowing it to plot all the points fixes the problem.

Comment: @aardvark2012 `ArrayPlot` seems to plot everything (note the much smaller cells).

Comment: As seen in the docs: "With the default setting `MaxPlotPoints -> Automatic`, sufficiently large or sparse matrices are downsampled so that their structure is visible in the plot generated by `MatrixPlot`." vs. the default `MaxPlotPoints -> Infinity` setting of `ArrayPlot[]`.

Comment: @kglr what downsampling? Is the screen effect the display effect?

Comment: @J.M. yes,the default option `MaxPlotPoints` is different for `ArrayPlot` and `MatrixPlot`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Seems that the automatic setting of [`MaxPlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxPlotPoints.html) is too low.  You can set it to something high (or even [`Infinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infinity.html)) to get around this.

```
m = 200;
list = Table[Table[RandomInteger[], {j, 1, 10}], {i, 1, m}];
Tally[Flatten[list]]
MatrixPlot[list, FrameTicks -> None, ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Red}, MaxPlotPoints -> ∞]
```

Comment: From the docs: "With the default setting `MaxPlotPoints -> Automatic`, sufficiently large or sparse matrices are downsampled so that their structure is visible in the plot generated by `MatrixPlot`." This seems to be what's happening here, and *Mathematica* is suitably interpolating colors to go along with this downsampling.

Comment: Looks like `MaxPlotPoints` needs to only be `Max@Dimensions@list`, although no harm with using ∞...

Comment: Thanks. Although, from reading the documentation, it is not clear to me why downsampling by altering the colors would give a more visible structure. So I don't really understand why *Mathematica* does this by default.

Answer (score 11):

**Update: How is the default setting for `MaxPlotPoints` determined?**

The function `` Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`checkMaxpoint `` is called to get the value of `MaxPlotPoints`. It takes three arguments. The first argument is the `data` array. The third argument is `True` if the calling function is `MatrixPlot`, `False` if it is `ArrayPlot.` The default value of `MaxPlotPoints` is obtained using `Automatic` as the second argument.

To illustrate on an example from the original answer below:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomInteger[1, {20, 300}];
```

For this `data`

```
{m, n} = Dimensions[data]
```

> {20, 300}

and the default value of `MaxPlotPoints` for `MatrixPlot` is

```
maxpoint = Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`checkMaxpoint[data, Automatic, True]
```

> {200, 200}

For `ArrayPlot` it is always `{∞, ∞}` regardless of `data` (*`ArrayPlot` plots everything*):

```
Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`checkMaxpoint[data, Automatic, False]
```

> {∞, ∞}

The function `` Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`checkMaxpoint `` turns the number `x` returned by the function  `` Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`MatrixPlotMaxPlotPoints `` into `{x, x}`.

```
Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`MatrixPlotMaxPlotPoints[data]
```

> 200

The core of this function is just

```
Min[1000, Max[100, 10  Min[Dimensions[data]]]]
```

> 200

So, for `MatrixPlot`, `{1000, 1000}` is the maximum possible value for `maxpoint` regardless of data dimensions.

**How is `maxpoint` used to downsample `data`?**

The function call `` Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`getCompressedMatrix[data, maxpoint, averaging] `` uses `maxpoint` to get the block sizes in vertical and horizontal directions:

```
{iblksize = Ceiling[m/Min[m, maxpoint[[1]]]], 
 jblksize = Ceiling[n/Min[n, maxpoint[[2]]]]}
{1, 2}
```

and calls the function `` Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`downsampleArray `` with two arguments, `data` and `{iblksize, jblksize}` which, in turn, partitions data into `iblksize *jblksize` blocks and replaces each block with its total value and returns an array with dimensions `Dimensions[data]/{iblksize, jblksize} = {20,150}`.  If `averaging` is `True` the calling function `` Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`getCompressedMatrix `` process the matrix to replace each array entry by the mean of associated block.

```
downsampleddata = Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`downsampleArray[data, {1, 2}];
Dimensions[downsampleddata]
```

> {20, 150}

The array `downsampleddata` is, effectively, the one plotted by `MatrixPlot`:

```
ImageData[MatrixPlot[downsampleddata, Frame -> False]] === 
 ImageData[MatrixPlot[data, Frame -> False]]
True
```

**Original answer**

[Documentation >> MatrixPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixPlot.html#171227984):

- *With the default setting `MaxPlotPoints -> Automatic`, sufficiently large or sparse matrices are downsampled so that their structure is visible in the plot generated by `MatrixPlot`.*

And [Documentation >> MatrixPlot >> Options >> MaxPlotPoints](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixPlot.html#226094680):

- *By default, automatic methods are used to downsample large and/or sparse matrices*

Setting the option value for `MaxPlotPoints` to `Infinity` or to `Dimensions[data]` prevents downsampling.

Example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomInteger[1, {20, 300}];
```

For a small subset of `data` we see only two colors:

```
Column[{MatrixPlot[data[[All, ;; 200]], Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 600],
  MatrixPlot[data[[All, ;; 200]], Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> Hue, ImageSize -> 600]}]
```

[image: matrix plots]

For full `data` we see the effect of downsampling:

```
Column[{MatrixPlot[data, Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 600],
  MatrixPlot[data, Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> Hue, ImageSize -> 600]}]
```

[image: matrix plots]

Setting the option value for `MaxPlotPoints` to `Infinity` or to `Dimensions[data]` prevents downsampling:

```
Column[{MatrixPlot[data, Frame -> False, 
   MaxPlotPoints -> Dimensions[data], ImageSize -> 600],
  MatrixPlot[data, Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
   MaxPlotPoints -> Dimensions[data], ImageSize -> 600]}]
```

[image: matrix plots]

Comment: I'm curious, why with `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` we get 2 colors for `ColorFunction -> Hue` but 3 colors for the default `ColorFunction`? Code: `Tally@Flatten[Cases[MatrixPlot[data,ColorFunction->Hue,ColorFunctionScaling -> False],_Raster,-1][[1,1]],1]`.

Comment: @Alexey, good observation. Don't know the answer off the top of my head.

Comment: I would like to merge this question into https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6615/using-uniform-coloring-in-matrixplot -- please let me know if you agree.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, sure; it _is_  a duplicate of [6615](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6615/using-uniform-coloring-in-matrixplot).

Answer (score 10):

As belisarius commented you can use [`ArrayPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html), which does not compress the range of the data.

```
list = RandomInteger[1, {10, 300}];

ArrayPlot[list, ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Red}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Perhaps better in this case you can also build the image raster directly:

```
Image[ list /. {0 -> {1, 1, 1}, 1 -> {1, 0, 0}} ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As an aside note, I think these beasts are safer when framed. Sometimes there is a deceiving lot of white space at the borders.

Comment: @belisarius in your opinion is throwing `Framed` on the second option sufficient?

Comment: Thank you! Why is it preferable to use `Image` rather than `ArrayPlot`?

Comment: @Andrew it may render and resize faster than the object produced by ArrayPlot, if you don't need the added features such as the frame that belisarius mentioned.  It can also be quite flexible as you work with the `{Red, Green, Blue}` values directly (or optionally another colorspace).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes. Anything showing a hint of where the "actual" borders are would do. My comment was not about asking you to modify the code, but to warn the OP about taking care of it. +1, BTW