# What is the fundamental difference between ArrayPlot and MatrixPlot?

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have a matrix called `data`. It seems that I can plot `data` using either `ArrayPlot` or `MatrixPlot`:

```
data = {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}};
imgSize = 200;
Grid[{{
   ArrayPlot[data, ImageSize -> imgSize],
   MatrixPlot[data, ImageSize -> imgSize]
   }}]
```

[image: plot1]

So, by default, `ArrayPlot` and `MatrixPlot` give just different styles, it seems. I can adjust style parameters to obtain the same style:

```
Grid[{{
   ArrayPlot[data, ImageSize -> imgSize, FrameTicks -> All, 
    ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Blue}],
   MatrixPlot[data, ImageSize -> imgSize, 
    ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Blue}]
   }}]
```

[image: plot2]

What, if anything, it is the fundamental difference between `ArrayPlot` and `MatrixPlot`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is speed vs. best visual representation question. In my experience `ArrayPlot` is much faster than `MatrixPlot` for large data sets:

```
data = Table[Sin[(-i^2 - j^2)/1000.^1.5], {i, 1000}, {j, 1000}];

Grid@Transpose@{MatrixPlot[data, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel] // 
    AbsoluteTiming, ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel] // AbsoluteTiming}
```

[image]

So if you need speed for large data sets go with `ArrayPlot`, or even `Raster`. But for visuals use `MatrixPlot`, especially when entries have a big range and many different values:

```
data = Fourier[Table[UnitStep[i, 4 - i] UnitStep[j, 7 - j], {i, -50, 50}, {j, -50, 50}]];
```

`MatrixPlot` colors negative entries with cool colors and positive entries with warm colors. ArrayPlot uses gray scale. MatrixPlot rescales the matrix entries to differentiate values over a wide range. Compare:

```
#[data] & /@ {ArrayPlot, MatrixPlot}
```

[image]

`SparseArray` usually gets much better representation from `MatrixPlot`:

```
#[Import[ToFileName[{"LinearAlgebraExamples", "Data"}, 
     "west0381.mtx"]]] & /@ {ArrayPlot, MatrixPlot}
```

[image]

I would also recommend to look at some other related plotting functions that act on arrays. Applicability really depends on the data type. For example in the case of geographical data `ReliefPlot` (the last one) is a winner:

```
#[Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/hailey.dem.gz", "Data"]] & /@ 
{ArrayPlot, Graphics[Raster[Rescale[#]]] &, MatrixPlot, ReliefPlot}
```

[image]

Usually it is a good thing to check the [**Properties and Relations**](http://wolfram.com/xid/0cqzvyzm-ctg) section in the Documentation.

Comment: It is a very old question, however, on the modern version and modern hardware, it might still be actual if displaying huge matrices. Then `Image@Rescale` or `Colorize@Image@Rescale` works the best for me.

    `Grid@Transpose@{MatrixPlot[data, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel] // 
    AbsoluteTiming, 
   ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel] // AbsoluteTiming, 
   Image@Rescale[data] // AbsoluteTiming}`

gives approximately 2s, 1s, and 5ms. And on a larger data (e.g. `data = DiskMatrix[1000, 4000]`) I get 1.8s, 5.6s and 0.18s.

Comment: @Oleg Have you tried my `renderImage` code from [(21482)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21482/121)?  I am curious how it compares on recent versions.  (I still use v10.1)

Answer (score 18):

You need to look no further than... [your own question!](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6615/5) A fundamental difference between the two is that `MatrixPlot` is used to "visualize" the data, whereas `ArrayPlot` is used to plot the array elements exactly. `MatrixPlot` does some sort of compression of the axes especially when you have an array that's long in one dimension and thin in the other. For example:

```
list = Table[Table[RandomInteger[], {j, 1, 10}], {i, 1, 200}];
{MatrixPlot[list, FrameTicks -> None, ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
    ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Red}],
 ArrayPlot[list, FrameTicks -> None, ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
    ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Red}]} // Row
```

[image]

You can see that `MatrixPlot` (left) has distorted the aspect ratio and interpolated the colours *even though* you gave explicit `ColorRules`, whereas `ArrayPlot` (right) plots it exactly. In order to make `MatrixPlot` behave similarly, you'll need to set `MaxPlotPoints` as in [Andy Ross' answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6616/5).

Comment: Thanks. I just realized that the answer was in my question from a few months ago. I am sorry for being so silly!

Comment: @Andrew, Your question is not silly. I found it useful!