# Use a symmetric mesh in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, mesh, antialiasing, axisymmetry

I am trying to produce a `ListDensityPlot` but I am having issues with aliasing. The problem arises from the way that Mathematica is breaking up the mesh into triangles, such that the orientations of the triangles is always in one direction, such that along one edge where there is a steep change in the function it appears smooth but along another edge is appears jagged. This is purely artificial due to the nature of the mesh, and could be solved if I could use a mesh which was somewhat more isotropic or which was axisymmetric about the center, but I cannot figure out how to do this. I'm surprised the mesh does not adapt where the derivative becomes large.

I am attaching two plots, with and without the mesh to demonstrate the issue. You can see aliasing on the top left and bottom right edges, whereas the top right and bottom left edges appear smooth. I am pretty certain this is caused by the mesh, as you can see in the second image the triangles are oriented differently along these different edges. The data set used to generate the plot is a simple square lattice. All help appreciated.

`ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"]`

[image: Note aliasing effect on the top left and bottom right sides]

`ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", Mesh->All]`

[image: Note orientation of triangles on the different edges]

Edit:

Changing the interpolation order does not fix the issue, as per Henrik's response:

```
GraphicsGrid[
  Partition[
    Table[ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
      InterpolationOrder -> i], {i, 1, 6}],
      3],
  ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image: Effect persists at different orders of interpolation]

Data used to generate this plot can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsIKVQvN2N7p50PNwBUFzOoHzCu6) or [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/NB7HGEnt).

Comment: Would you please post the code that produced the plots?

Comment: You could try adding the option `InterpolationOrder -> 3`...

Comment: Can I attach a file with the data points?

Comment: added a link to include the data file

Comment: I just want to point out this is still apparently an issue in Mathematica 12

Comment: The issue is still present in Mathematica 13.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a random example:

```
f = {x, y} \[Function] Sin[7 Pi (x + y)] + 0.7 Cos[12 (-1 x + 2 y + 1.)];
n = 25;
{x, y} = Transpose[Outer[List, Subdivide[0., 1., n], Subdivide[0., 1., n], 1], {2, 3, 1}];
data = f[x, y];
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
  Table[ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> i], {i, 1, 6}],
  3], ImageSize -> Large
 ]
```

[image]

So the mesh is not necessarily the issue.

Usually, the option `MaxPlotPoints` should help. But for some reason, it doesn't. So, let's upsample the image by hand: After download, we load the data, create an interpolation function and sample that on a finer grid.

```
data = Import["example_SF.mx"];
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
resolution = 400;
upsampledvals = Outer[f, 
 Subdivide[0., 4., resolution], 
 Subdivide[0., 4., resolution], 
 1];
```

Now we have the upsampled data but how to render it? Fortunately, @Wizard provided us in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21488/38178) with an efficient method to use `Image` with a costumized color pallete:

```
renderImage[array_?MatrixQ, cf_, q_Integer: 2048, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[Image]] := 
 Module[{tbl}, 
  tbl = List @@@ Array[cf, q, {0`, 1`}] // N // 
    Developer`ToPackedArray;
  Image[tbl[[# + 1]] & /@ Round[(q - 1`) array], opts]]
```

Applying it to the upsampled date leads to

```
img = renderImage[Rescale[upsampledvals], ColorData["SunsetColors"]]
```

[image]

So far, this missed the axes. Those can be added like this:

```
Graphics[
 Inset[img, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {4, 4}],
 Axes -> True,
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}},
 PlotRangePadding -> 0.1
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, changing the interpolation order does not affect my results, I'm updating the question

Comment: Hi @Kai, I edited my answer and provided a workaround. However, I would classify that behavior at least as undesired and it might be worthwile to contact the support about it...

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely do that. I'm confused what you're doing in the second part with the axes? Also, the second image you provided seems be lower resolution than the first.

Comment: btw, I think you meant "But for some reason, it doesn't"

Comment: Oops. I corrected it. Towards the axes: I put the `Image` with `Inset` into the plain (with appropriate scaling) and just activate the axes (and some other cosmetics). Have a look at `Inset` in the documentation.

Comment: Oh I see now what you meant by axes, I didn't even notice the bounding box. Thanks!

Comment: I submitted it to support and they replied and said they forwarded it to the devs

Comment: That's what they use to say... =)