# Plane surface data plot

Tags: plotting

I want to generate a plot like this:

[image: Target plot]

I generated this list

```
list = {{-1., -1, 0}, {-0.894737, -1, 0}, {-0.789474, -1, 0},
{-0.684211, -1, 0}, {-0.578947, -1, 0}, {-0.473684, -1, 0}, 
{-0.368421, -1, 0}, {-0.263158, -1, 0}, {-0.157895, -1, 0}, 
{-0.052631, -1, 0}, {0.0526316, -1, 0}, {0.1578950, -1, 0}, 
{0.2631580, -1, 0}, {0.3684210, -1, 0}, {0.4736840, -1, 0}, 
{0.5789470, -1, 0}, {0.6842110, -1, 0}, {0.7894740, -1, 0}, 
{0.8947370, -1, 0}, {1., -1, 0}}
```

and I thought that it'll fine for generate the first row, but instead, I get an empty plot using:

```
ListPlot3D[list]
```

The only way I'm getting something is taking off the third entry from every triad in the list:

[image: Not desired]

But evidently that's not what i'm looking for, thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Yeah, my question is not clear, sorry about that. I've generated that list with a Table. What I'm looking for is to plot the square (with 400 equal partitions) centered in the origin of a cartesian coordinates system showing the value of the point. The problem with ArrayPlot is that the axes show the position of the data in the list, and not the value of the point.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to generate that plot with some fake data or want to plot your list?

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you want?

```
list2 = list[[All, 1]];
Legended[ArrayPlot[list2~Partition~5, 
  ColorFunction -> "WatermelonColors", FrameTicks -> True], 
 BarLegend[{"WatermelonColors", {-1, 1}}]]
```

[image]

**Edit:**

```
list = Table[x y, {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}];

Legended[ArrayPlot[list, ColorFunction -> "WatermelonColors", 
  Frame -> False, Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Black, 
  DataReversed -> True], BarLegend[{"WatermelonColors", {-1, 1}}]]
```

[image]

**Edit 2**

```
list = Table[x y, {x, -1, 1, 2/19}, {y, -1, 1, 2/19}];


 ArrayPlot[list, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Frame -> False, 
 Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Black, DataReversed -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**Edit 3** You can remove the `GridLines`

```
list = Table[x y, {x, -1, 1, 2/19}, {y, -1, 1, 2/19}]; p2 = 
 ArrayPlot[list, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Mesh -> True, 
  MeshStyle -> Black, ImagePadding -> None, DataReversed -> True, 
  Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 95];
p1 = ListPlot[{{0, 0}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   PlotRange -> {{-4, 4.4}, {-2, 2.4}}, ImageSize -> 400, 
   AspectRatio -> Full, 
   FrameTicks -> {{{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}, None}, {{-4, -2, 0, 2, 4}, 
      None}}, GridLines -> {{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}}];
Legended[Overlay[{p1, p2}, Alignment -> Center], 
 BarLegend[{"BlueGreenYellow", {-1, 1}}, LegendMarkerSize -> 200, 
  Ticks -> {-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}]]
```

[image]

**Edit 4**  Here is better and perfect figure.(I assume you don't insist black mesh on figure). I got the idea from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166475/use-a-symmetric-mesh-in-listdensityplot/%22here%22)

```
  data = Reverse@Table[x y, {x, -1, 1, 2/19}, {y, -1, 1, 2/19}];
renderImage[array_?MatrixQ, cf_, q_Integer: 2048, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[Image]] := 
 Module[{tbl}, 
  tbl = List @@@ Array[cf, q, {0`, 1`}] // N // 
    Developer`ToPackedArray;
  Image[tbl[[# + 1]] & /@ Round[(q - 1`) array], opts]]
img = renderImage[Rescale[data], ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"]];

Legended[Graphics[Inset[img, {-1, -1}, {0, 0}, {2, 2}], Axes -> True, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}, None}, {{-4, -2, 0, 2, 4}, 
     None}}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-2, 2}}, 
  GridLines -> {{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}}], 
 BarLegend[{"BlueGreenYellow", {-1, 1}}, LegendMarkerSize -> 200, 
  Ticks -> {-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}]]
```

[image]

[image]

Here how you can add Mesh on plot.

```
data = Table[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1, 2/19}, {y, -1, 1, 2/19}];
grid = Extract[#, {{1}, {-1}}] & /@ data;
grid2 = Extract[#, {{1}, {-1}}] & /@ Transpose@data;
Legended[Graphics[{Inset[img, {-1, -1}, {0, 0}, {2, 2}], Black, 
   Opacity@1, Line[#] & /@ grid1, Line[#] & /@ grid2}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}, None}, {{-4, -2, 0, 2, 4}, 
     None}}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1/2], 
 BarLegend[{"BlueGreenYellow", {-1, 1}}, LegendMarkerSize -> 200, 
  Ticks -> {-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}]]
```

[image]

Can someone explain why this does not work well? img should fit [-1,1]x[-1,1]

```
data = Table[x y, {x, -1, 1, 2/19}, {y, -1, 1, 2/19}];
img = ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
  Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Black, DataReversed -> True, 
  ImageMargins -> 0, ImagePadding -> None, 
  ImageSize -> 270]; Graphics[Inset[img, {-1, -1}, {0, 0}, {2, 2}], 
 Axes -> True, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-2, 2}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}, None}, {{-4, -2, 0, 2, 4}, None}},
  GridLines -> {{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like that. Maybe I need to manipulate your code, or my list. I want a plot of a square from [-1,1]x[-1,1] with 20 squares per side. Let me work on it and I tell you.

Comment: you should replace 0.1 with 2/19 to get 20 square per side in `Table`

Comment: Wow, thanks man, that's what I needed!

Comment: Thanks again!! Now i'm know about this functions, it's been very helpfu!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another simple way using [`ListDensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html) which is in some sense the "right" way if this data is to be interpreted as continuous.

```
ListDensityPlot[list = Table[x y, {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}], 
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

If you want the plot legend `PlotLegends -> Automatic` will do that for you.