# How to take advantage of symmetries of a function when making its `DensityPlot`?

Tags: plotting

I want to obtain a density plot of a function `fun[x, y]` that is slow to evaluate. It takes many hours to get a density plot. As a simple example, we define the following function:

```
fun[x_, y_] := (Pause[0.0001]; Sin[x y]^2)
```

We want to obtain the following density plot:

```
DensityPlot[fun[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Since this function has symmetries $x\to -x$ and $y\to -y$, the information in the first quadrant is sufficient.

```
DensityPlot[fun[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

In my computer, it takes 2.78 seconds to get the first plot, while 1.56 seconds to get the second one. When we use the second plot to save some time, how to obtain the first plot by using the result of the second plot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ClearAll[reflectF]
reflectF = Show[#, MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, 
   ReflectionTransform /@ {{-1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, -1}}] &, #, {1}], 
  PlotRange -> All] &;
```

Example:

```
DensityPlot[fun[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

```
(dp = DensityPlot[fun[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

```
reflectF @ dp // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a `Table` and use [`ListDensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html).

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x,y,fun[x, y]},{x, -2, 2, 0.1},{y, -2, 2, 0.1}], 1];//AbsoluteTiming
ListDensityPlot[data] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.004211, Null}

[image]

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x,y,fun[x, y]},{x,0,2,0.1},{y,0,2,0.1}],1]; // AbsoluteTiming
data = Join[data, data /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {-x, y, z}, 
                  data /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {-x, -y, z}, 
                  data /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {x, -y, z}]; // AbsoluteTiming
ListDensityPlot[data] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.001187, Null}
>
> {0.001483, Null}

[image]

You would see a significant reduction in time when using a complicated function where evaluation requires more time compared to plotting.

**To use the Mathe-Mesh**

```
mesh = DensityPlot[fun[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotPoints -> 10][[1, 1]];
data = Table[{p[[1]], p[[2]], fun[p[[1]], p[[2]]]}, {p, mesh}]; 

data = Join[data, data /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {-x, y, z}, 
                  data /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {-x, -y, z}, 
                  data /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {x, -y, z}]; // AbsoluteTiming

ListDensityPlot[data, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

The number of mesh points can be controlled by  `PlotPoints` in `mesh`

Comment: Nice, although the adaptive Mathematica mesh is replaced by the regular one.

Comment: Adaptive mesh is very necessary in some cases. I wonder how to use the data extracted from DensityPlot to make another density plot.

Comment: @renphysics, I hope the modified answer would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Reap`/`Sow` to get the function's values as MA tabulates the function for plot:

```
fun[x_, y_] := Sin[x y]^2
{graph, {data}} = 
  Reap[DensityPlot[z = fun[x, y]; Sow[{x, y, z}]; 
             z, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]];

Clear[z]
tmp = Cases[
   data, {x_/;NumberQ[x], y_/;NumberQ[y], 
     z_} -> {{x, y, z}, {-x, y, z}, {-x, -y, z}, {x, -y, z}}];
symdata = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[tmp, 1]];

ListDensityPlot[sym]
```

Notice, the function is evaluated only in the `DensityPlot`

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is quality then you can use this which is also pretty fast. You can find the code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166475/use-a-symmetric-mesh-in-listdensityplot/%22here%22).

```
fun[x_, y_] := Sin[x y]^2
data = Table[fun[x, y], {x, -2, 2, 0.005}, {y, -2, 2, 0.005}];

renderImage[array_?MatrixQ, cf_, q_Integer: 2048, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[Image]] := 
 Module[{tbl}, 
  tbl = List @@@ Array[cf, q, {0`, 1`}] // N // 
    Developer`ToPackedArray;
  Image[tbl[[# + 1]] & /@ Round[(q - 1`) array], opts]]

img = renderImage[Rescale[data], 
   ColorData["M10DefaultDensityGradient"]];

Graphics[Inset[img, {-2, -2}, {0, 0}, {4, 4}], Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0.1]
```

[image]