# MatrixPlot with only white and black but no brown

Tags: plotting

Thanks to MatrixPlot, I can observe some patterns in a matrix.
However, when I use MatrixPlot :

```
MatrixPlot[A, ColorFunction -> "Monochrome"]
```

The matrix is colored with 3 colors :
 - black
 - white
 - brown

Is it possible to color the matrix only with 2 colors :
 - black when there is something not null
 - white when the element is null ?

Comment: Why not use `ArrayPlot[]` instead?

Comment: Related: [(6615)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6615/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dat = RandomChoice[{Null, 0, 5}, {3, 3}];
MatrixPlot[dat, ColorFunction -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can replace `Null` with `None`:

> `None` is interpreted as a missing value and displayed using transparency

```
MatrixPlot[dat /. Null -> None, ColorFunction -> "Monochrome"]
```

Or, use `ColorRules` to display `Null` as `White`:

```
MatrixPlot[dat, ColorFunction -> "Monochrome", ColorRules -> {Null -> White}]
```

Alternatively, use `ColorRules` to specify the colors directly,

```
MatrixPlot[dat, ColorRules -> {Null | 0 -> White, _ -> Black}]
```

All three approaches above give:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To display `Null` as `White` and all other values as `Black`, use

```
MatrixPlot[dat, ColorRules -> {Null -> White, _ -> Black}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]